# Dapr State Store - Is there an equivalent of the Redis KEYS command?

Tags: redis, dapr

I was wondering if Dapr has the option to get the functionality that Redis provides with the [KEYS](https://redis.io/commands/keys/) command. For instance, I would like to be able to get all keys where the key matches a specific pattern like: `KEYS *name*`